# Best way to handle multiple table query linked to "main" table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I am tracking visitor sessions and have a "master" table that contains the session start, end and some visitor info.

```
CREATE TABLE "sessions" (
    session_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    session_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    session_end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    user_ip TEXT NOT NULL,
    user_agent TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

For each session I have three metrics - pageviews, downloads and video plays. Each table follows this formula

```
CREATE TABLE "sessions_<x>" (
    session_id BIGINT REFERENCES sessions (session_id),
    data_1 TEXT NOT NULL,
    data_2 TEXT NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

The three tables are not identical, but the data itself is not important - the only thing they share is the `session_id` reference to the `sessions` table.

Data is inserted so, in a single transaction, the relevant pageview/download/video play record is added and the `session_start` / `session_end` is updated.

For my code, I wish to extract each session with associated pageviews, downloads and video plays. In an effort to minimize the number of queries I figured I'd do the following:

1. Do a query on the `sessions` table to get the identifying information + `session_id` for each session.
2. For each of the three metric tables, do a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE session_id IN (<sessions>)`
3. In code, "collect" the data from each result set from #2 and associate it with the base session information.

I am wondering if this is the best approach. I have some worries that for large data sets this might be a bad idea (lots of in-memory data at a time), but is there an alternative where I can in one query get session information + associated metrics (for all three tables) easily? Or at least in a way where I can iterate through it in my program one session at a time?

This is not a user-facing web service, so super-fast, sub-second replies are not the goal, but performance is a factor. The service is being built in python if it matters and I am using postgresql 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM session s
LEFT OUTER JOIN session_<x> sx
ON s.session_id = sx.session_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN session_<y> sy
ON s.session_id = sy.session_id;
```

Comment: That works for one table, but it still amounts to three queries (one for each table). Since multiple

Comment: Simply join on other tables too

Comment: @ChristianP. Do you where successful?

Comment: If you join the other tables, you get too many rows.

Imagine one session record, two downloads and four pageviews. You would end up with the session record repeated (fine), the two downloads repeated 4 times (not good) and the pageviews repeated 2 times (not good).

I ended up doing it like I originally described, for now anyway.